# sudo start my-project does not work

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, upstart, exec

I'm using the following script in `/etc/init/my-project.conf` on my AWS instance.

```
description "start and stop the go program 'my-project'"

start on filesystem or runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

env USER='ec2-user'
env APP_DIR='/home/ec2-user/go/src/bitbucket.com/xxx/my-project/'
env APP_EXEC='my-project'

exec start-stop-daemon —start —chuid ${USER} —chdir ${APP_DIR} —exec ${APP_DIR}${APP_EXEC}
```

`service my-project start` command gives `unrecognized service` error. `sudo start my-project` starts a process which is not my project. When I run `sudo status my-project` command I get `my-project stop/waiting`. I couldn't find what I'm doing wrong.

In the path `/home/ec2-user/go/src/bitbucket.com/xxx/my-project/` there is an executable file named `my-project`. So basically `/home/ec2-user/go/src/bitbucket.com/xxx/my-project/my-project` runs the executable.

Answer (score 1):

First off the "service" command is for the "System V init scripts" found in /etc/init.d not the Upstart configs found in /etc/init. For Upstart you want to use "initctl". The equivalent of

```
$ service --status-all
```

for Upstart is

```
$ initctl list
```

Using the example upstart config found at https://gist.github.com/c4milo/940909 as a guide, I was able to get an Upstart configuration to run using the following:

```
    #description "start and stop the go program 'my-project'"

    start on filesystem or runlevel [2345]
    stop on runlevel [!2345]

    script

    USER='ec2-user'
    APP_DIR='/home/ec2-user/go/src/bitbucket.com/xxx/my-project/'
    APP_EXEC='my-project'

    su - ${USER} -c "exec ${APP_DIR}${APP_EXEC}"

    end script
```

If your changes to /etc/init/my-project.conf do not take effect you can try to force a reload with:

```
$ initctl reload-configuration
```

I was also able to remove the use of "env" as it was unnecessary.